# Laravel error using with() method in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to call using `with()` method in Laravel Eloquent ORM, but getting the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()
>   must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder,
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany given

I'm using the latest version of Laravel 6. Any ideas what might have caused this?

**Controller**

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function formIndex(Request $request)
    {
        $id = auth()->user()->id;
        $item = Groupe::find($id)->with(
            [
                'etudiants' => function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->select('id');
                }
            ]
        )->first();

        return $item;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
class Groupe extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    public function etudiants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Etudiant');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from the type hint you put on the $query variable, as the error message said the object that gets passed in there is a relationship not a raw Query Builder. Just remove the type hint. Also ::find() executes a query, so you're be executing 2 queries, use the query below instead

```php
Groupe::where('id', $id)->with(['etudiants' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id');
    }])->first();
```

Additionally, you don't need to use the callback syntax to only eager load certain columns, the callback syntax is for putting contraints on which records get returned. Try this instead.

```php
Groupe::where('id', $id)->with('etudiants:id,name,email')->first();
```

Comment: make sure to also select the foreign key for the relationship

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, with adding the foreign key to the query

Comment: And Hell Broke loose because of that one type hint xD .. thanks a lot it really helped, never would've guessed it in million years

Comment: The Laravel Documentation is giving exact this example. The documentation is wrong. Indeed without typehint it works.

Answer (score 0):

But what do you want return? groupe->students[]?? you can use

```
    $item = Groupe::where('id',$id)->with('etudiants')->first();
```

Comment: Yes I want to return that students data, but with specified columns, like name, email not all fields

Comment: ok so you can use protected $hidden = ['id','created_at','others'] in the model

Answer (score 0):

le probleme viens tous simplement de limport du builder utilise ceci
"use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).